# Debug so file in Android Studio 3

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, java-native-interface

I have a project that by historical reasons I can compile only on VS + old NDK.
The result is an so file which originally then was wrapped into an apk, so there is no way to debug it in VS.

I have created a new project in Android Studio that loads the library in hopes that having the source code I will be able to debug it in Android friendly environment, but all I could was stepping through the so functions without any feedback, moreover, AS strips the so file, despite project is set to compile for debug.

Is there a method to utilyse the source code to make debugging easier in Android Studio?